# How can I set template from a variable from parent component? Angular 2, Ionic 2

Tags: angular, templates, ionic2

I have 2 components. Child and parent. In the parent component I have a variable which is contains template for child.

How can I set template of child component from variable?

```js
@Component({
   template: "<button (click)='showChildComponent()'></button>"
})

export class parentComponent{
  variable = "<div>Hello world</div>";

  constructor(params: NavController)
  {

  }

  showChildComponent()
  {
    this.nav.push(ChildComponent, {template: this.variable});
  } 
}
```

Child:

```js
@Component()

export class ChildComponent{
   constructor(params: NavParams)
   {
       let template = this.params.get('template');
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead you should try have 5 components. And each having their on HTML. So based on the parent, you shift between the components. I doubt you can change the tenplate url from component.

Comment: Because @component is loaded first, then class.

Comment: And what about variable in window?

Comment: Then it will more of a JavaScript approach. There are other ways to like you can use `document` to load up a html and stuff. Then you might have issues with Angular2 controls.